# How do I copy vector graphics out of a PDF?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, vector-graphics

How do I copy a vector image out of a PDF file in Acrobat Pro? Currently what I have to do is use the Acrobat screenshot tool to make a bitmap copy, but what I want is the actual vector graphic in the file.

Comment: Acrobat Pro might not be the correct tool. Use a vector editing program, e.g. [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).

Comment: @DanielAndersson I can only use the tools I have at work. Getting a new one (even free) involves asking several people.

Comment: Well, then you are stuck with a spoon when what you really need is a screwdriver :-) .